# WooCommerce PayPal incorrect sum

Tags: wordpress, paypal, woocommerce

i use this plugin for paypal express: 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-gateway-paypal-express-checkout/ 
this works fine.

now i would like add an extra fee if my customer chose paypal as payment method. 
For this I bought and installed this plugin:
https://www.woothemes.com/products/payment-gateway-based-fees/

All looks good. i can chose the paypal express payment und the fee (12€) will automatically add to the sum (in my shopping cart).

but if I would pay and the paypal page will be open, there is only the sum WITHOUT the fee. What is wrong?
[image]

Comment: Kindly, [**Here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36787150/woocommerce-add-shipping-costs-and-add-an-extra-fee-for-paypal-pements/36787623#36787623) you have the same issue than yours… with the correct answer.

Comment: where is there the solution? there is only the answer hat I have to use the premium version, because in this post i use the lite version. now i use the premium version and i have the same issue

Comment: So the best way for plugins issues in general is to search and ask first in support threads. For premium plugins, you can open a support ticket. Plugin issues are off-topic in general in here.

Comment: i submit a ticket. but no answer until yet. i thought somebody can hell me here

Comment: If you have set custom code, people can help. If not, it's a bug in one of the plugins or in their relation and that has to do with support team of those plugins… Is too complicated for people here to help, because it is about commercial plugins that they can't access without buying them. See [on-topic questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in help center…